# Modify src of iframe only when youtube url loaded (jQuery or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Can someone kindly show me a javascript that will append this string:

```
&showinfo=0
```

to an iframe src attribute but only if the src contains youtube.com

So therefore this tag:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yso_Ez691qw?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Will become:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yso_Ez691qw?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

But only only on youtube urls not other iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would select all IFrames that contain string `youtube` in their `src` attribute, and append the string `&showinfo=0` to its src attribute.

```
$("iframe[src*='youtube']").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src + '&showinfo=0');
});
```

You may want to tweak it based on your requirements though:

- For instance, you can check entire youtube URL instead of just 'youtube'.
- Also, you might want to check if the querystring is not already part of the URL before appending it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets break this down into steps:

1. Loops through every iframe on the page
2. Check if the src of that iframe contains 'youtube'
3. Update the iframe's src attribute

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // here is the loop
  $('iframe').each(function(i) {
    // here we get the iframe's source
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var substring = 'youtube';
    // check if this iframe's source (src) contains 'youtube'
    if(src.indexOf(substring) !== -1) {
      // OK it does - lets update the source (src)
      $(this).attr('src', src + '&showinfo=0');
      console.log($(this).attr('src'));
      // https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yso_Ez691qw?feature=oembed&showinfo=0
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Really nice. Thanks for sharing this.